# How to open new terminal, execl

Tags: c++, qt, process, terminal, os.execl

Are there any ways to open new terminal using execl() or execlp. Smt like gnome-terminal -x?
Already tried it before path, doesn't work. If not, mb it is possible to open new terminal when process starts running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my use of execl in order to open xterm:

```
execl ("/usr/bin/xterm", "xterm", "-bd", "black", "-bg", "black",
"-fg", "green", "-geometry", "70x15+330+190", "-T", "ftp", "-e",
"ftp", (char *) 0);
```

Comment: after -e beggins path and par for my process, i guess?

Comment: You need to change it a little bit that one is for ftp.

Comment: oh i see, but it works musc slowlier than terminal(. One thing is interesting for me. PID executed with xtern will be the same that gave fork?

Comment: Yes should be the same.